# Data loss occurs when data is transmitted using shared memory In C linux

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program that receives data from the UDP process and delivers it to the next process through shared memory. However, I used semaphores and threads because I didn't want to use usleep(). When you receive data from UDP through the thread, you will be asked to queue the data and the main thread will write the data in shared memory through dequeue. However, data losses still occur, and I wonder why this occurs. If you still use usleep(), the data losses disappears.

I also used mutex for enqueue and dequeue. These symptoms are okay when transmitting small data, but when transmitting text larger than the buffer size, there is an omission in data transmission.

rcv from UDP&write on shared memory

Queuqe

```
#include "header.h"
#define PORTNUM 8887


//Queue//

typedef struct Node {
    char *data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
    int count;
}Queue;

void initQueue(Queue* queue) {
    queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    queue->count = 0;
}

int isEmpty(Queue* queue) {
    return queue->count == 0;
}

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void enqueue(Queue* queue, char* ddata) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data =(char *)malloc(strlen(ddata) + 1);
    memset(newNode->data, 0x00, strlen(ddata) + 1);
    strcpy(newNode->data, ddata);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (isEmpty(queue))
        queue->front = newNode;
    else
        queue->rear->next = newNode;
    queue->rear = newNode;
    queue->count++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

char* dequeue(Queue* queue) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    static char data[MAX_BUF_SIZE + 1];
    memset(data, 0x00, MAX_BUF_SIZE + 1);
    Node* ptr;
    if (isEmpty(queue)) {
        printf("Error : Queue is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    ptr = queue->front;
    strcpy(data, ptr->data);
    queue->front = ptr->next;
    free(ptr);
    queue->count--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return data;
}
```

semaphore and thread

```
//semaphore union//
union semun{
    int val;
    struct semid_dsi* sem;
    unsigned short int* array;
};

//thread//
typedef struct Trcv{
    int sd;
    Queue squeue;
}Trcv;

void *rcv(void *p){
    char buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE+1];
    
    Trcv *pp = (Trcv *)p;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    int len = sizeof(serv);

    while(1){
        memset(buf, 0x00, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1);
        if((recvfrom(pp->sd, buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, (socklen_t *)&len)) == -1){
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
        enqueue(&pp->squeue, buf);
    }
}
```

main

```
int main(){
    Queue queue;
    initQueue(&queue);

    Trcv trcv;
    int shm_id;
    int sem_id;

    char text[MAX_BUF_SIZE+1];
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    int bsize;

    int cnt = 0;
    int total = 0;


    if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((char *)&serv, '\0', sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &bsize, sizeof(bsize));

    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(serv)) == -1){
            perror("bind");
            exit(1);
    }

    //shared memory//
    key_t shm_key;
    void *buf;

    //semaphore//
    key_t sem_key;

    union semun sem_u;
    struct sembuf mysem_open  = {0, -1, SEM_UNDO};
    struct sembuf mysem_close = {0,  1, SEM_UNDO};


    shm_key = 1123;
    if((shm_id = shmget(shm_key, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1, IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1){
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((buf = (void *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1){
        perror("SM shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    //semaphore//
    sem_key = 1234;
    if((sem_id = semget(sem_key, 1, IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1){
        printf("semapore segment already exist\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("new semapore segment created\n");


    //semaphore value setting//
    sem_u.val = 1;
    semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, sem_u);
    /////////////////
    
    pthread_t pt_rcv;

    trcv.sd = sd;
    trcv.squeue = queue;
    
    pthread_create(&pt_rcv, NULL, rcv, (void *)&trcv);
    

    while(1){
        if(!isEmpty(&trcv.squeue)){
            if(semop(sem_id, &mysem_open, 1) == -1){//open
                perror("semop");
                exit(1);
            }
            memset(text, 0x00, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1);
            strncpy(text, dequeue(&trcv.squeue), MAX_BUF_SIZE);

            printf("%s\n",text);
            cnt = strlen(text);
            total += cnt;
            printf("\n======================\n");
            printf("size : %d\n",cnt);
            printf("total : %d\n",total);
            printf("======================\n\n");
        
            memcpy(buf, text, MAX_BUF_SIZE);
            semop(sem_id, &mysem_close, 1);//close
        }
        //usleep(30000);
    }
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    shmdt(buf);
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

read from shared memory

```
#include "header.h"
#include <log.h>

int main(){
    //shared memroy//
    key_t shm_key;
    void *buf;//void *shmaddr
    char text[MAX_BUF_SIZE+1];

    //semapore//
    key_t sem_key;
    struct sembuf mysem_open = {0, -1, SEM_UNDO};//open sem
    struct sembuf mysem_close = {0, 1, SEM_UNDO};//close sem

    int shm_id;a
    int sem_id;

    int cnt = 0;
    int total = 0;

    if(access("result.txt", F_OK) == 0){
        unlink("result.txt");
        printf("result file unlinked\n");
    }
```

I'm going to print out the text I received as a file.

```
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    
    LogSetup();

    shm_key = 1123;
    if((shm_id = shmget(shm_key, 0, 0)) == -1){
        LOG_ERROR("shmget ERR");    
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        LOG_TRACE("shmget id : %d",shm_id);


    if((buf = (void *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0))==(void *)-1){
        LOG_FATAL("shmat ERR");
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        LOG_DEBUG("BUF");
    

    sem_key = 1234;
    LOG_TRACE("TRACE");
    if((sem_id = semget(sem_key, 1, IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1){
        LOG_ERROR("segmet ERR");
        printf("Semapore segment alreday exist\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("new semapore segment created\n");   
        LOG_ERROR("semget id : %d",sem_id);
    }

    while(1){
        if((semop(sem_id, &mysem_open, 1)) == -1){//open sema
            LOG_ERROR("semaphore open ERR");
            perror("semop");
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(text, 0x00, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1);
        strncpy(text,(char *)buf, MAX_BUF_SIZE);


        if(strncmp(text,"",MAX_BUF_SIZE) != 0){
            fp = fopen("result.txt","a");
            
            printf("%s\n",text);
            fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), fp);
        
            fclose(fp);

            cnt = strlen(text);
            total += cnt;

            printf("\n======================\n");
            printf("size : %d\n",cnt);
            printf("total : %d\n",total);
            printf("======================\n\n");   
            LOG_INFO("Recv text : %s",text);
            LOG_INFO("total size : %d",total);
        
        }
        memset(buf, 0x00, MAX_BUF_SIZE+1);
        
        if(semop(sem_id, &mysem_close,1) == -1){
            LOG_ERROR("semaphore close ERR");
            perror("semop");
            exit(1);
        }
        
    }   
    shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    shmdt(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a race condition if usleep is effecting the results of your data.

Comment: Maybe use pipes

Comment: Show the code please.  [mcve]

Comment: Maybe because of UDP does not guarantee to be sent. Unrelated but there is a bug in `if (isEmpty(queue))` condition -> you should unlock the mutex.

Comment: Thank you. I changed like this
```if (isEmpty(queue)) {printf("Error : Queue is empty\n");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
return 0;
 }```

Comment: @NateEldredge I added code